# Drive permissions in ubuntu

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-18.04

I have this window's drive shared and mounted in ubuntu. And recently the drive access became read-only for ubuntu and I want to change its permissions.
:~$ sudo chmod -R 755 * did not work for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is it shared?

Comment: The system is dual booted and the drive is a window's partition accessible from ubuntu.

Comment: It could be that the drive is not in a "clean" state - ie the indexes need to ne checked - something Linux is not good at on ntfs drives - so its read-only so as nit to compound damage. Rebooting to windows, checking the drive then safely ejecting ;unmojnting it cpyld fix the issue. If issue persists it might be worth looking at changing the drive to exfat.

Comment: Rebooting to windows and changing permissions from there worked.                             Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dual boot ubuntu with windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/807490/dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-8)